# Appscript Google addEdtor(row[5]) permission.value error

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets

Sheet:
list of user's names row[0]
list of user emails row[5]

run the script it works fine apart from this line

```js
 DriveApp.getFileById('1phsJs4ik2a654645645GOJs4gBVVKd2OmlHtlPk').makeCopy(sheetName,dest).addEditor(owner);
```

ERROR: Invalid argument: permission.value (line 21, file "Code")

Works fine when i replace the 'owner' with '"email@google.com"' but i need it to iterate through a list

Full code:

```js
// Showing it has been sent.
var Confirmed = "Confirmed";

function DistributeTemplate() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var specify = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var counter = specify.getRange("A1").getValue(); //HOW MANY TO DO 
var numRows = counter;   // Number of rows to process
 var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 var dest = DriveApp.getFolderById('INSERTFOLDERID');
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
 var row = data[i];
 var sheetName = row[0]   
 var FlexisheetSent = row[2];   
 var owner = row[5];
 Logger.log(owner);
  if (FlexisheetSent != Confirmed) { //Only send once
    //DriveApp.getFolderById(dest).addEditor(owner);
   DriveApp.getFileById('INSERTTEMPLATEIDGOOGLESHEET').makeCopy(sh eetName,dest).addEditor(owner);
   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(Confirmed);
     // The cell is updated instantly to avoid any issues.
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no value `row[5]`.

At this line:

```
var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)
```

The configuration of the parameters of the **[getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))** you're using is: `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`

That gets you an Array of 5 elements `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]`, but you refer to an Array element by referring to the index number and Array indexes start with 0.

You either need change your `var owner = row[5];` to `var owner = row[4];` if the email is in your E column or `var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)` to `var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6)` if the email is in the F column of your Spreadsheet.

Also be sure that the cell that has the email doesn't have leading or trailing whitespaces, or any other special character.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the big check mark.  That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct.

Comment: That's done!, i would have done this earlier if i'd known. Could you check my other post out if you have some time. Thanks again Ocordova!