# Invalid argument: permission.value

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting

Script keeps giving me this error message. "Invalid argument: permission.value"
This is the part of the code the error points out to:

```
var buyer   = threads[i].getMessages()[0].getReplyTo();
var subject = "Thank you for your purchase";
var body    = "Please download the file using the link below.\n\n";

if (size > 20) {
    file.addViewer(buyer); <---- It specifically points to this line
```

Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: Please add better tags to your question to reach people who might be interested by your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the error **Invalid argument: permission.value** if the referenced item doesn't exist. In your code, this might be the case if the index `i` is out of range, or `threads[i]` doesn't reference an object, or `getMessages()[0]` returns no object.

Run your script in debug mode, and when the error occurs, you can view the contents of your variables to see what the problem is.

See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671982/appscript-google-addedtorrow5-permission-value-error).

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the buyer variable with an email address, it works fine.

`.getReplyTo()` pulls a name and an email address from <>. ie `"Name""< name@gmail.com>"`